# How to check if an attribute is present in an xml node using xmllint

Tags: bash, xmllint

I'm using `bash` and `xmllint` to check nodes in the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
<document>
    <sentence id="13">
        <text>This is a test sentence.</text>
        <entities>
            <annotation id="3">
                <grammar-form id="0" normal-form="THIS"/>
            </annotation>
            <annotation id="4">
                <grammar-form id="0" normal-form="IS"/>
            </annotation>
            <annotation id="5">
                <grammar-form id="0" normal-form="A"/>
            </annotation>
            <annotation id="6">
                <grammar-form id="0" normal-form="TEST"/>
            </annotation>
            <annotation id="7">
                <grammar-form id="0" normal-form="SENTENCE"/>
            </annotation>
            <annotation id="12">
                <grammar-form id="0" normal-form="."/>
            </annotation>
        </entities>
    </sentence>
</document>
</output>
```

How can I simply check that each `grammar-form` node has a `normal-form` attribute present? It doesn't matter what the attribute value is, I just need to check that it is present.

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to select `grammar-form`s that *don't* have the attribute and see if you get any matches or not:

```sh
if xmllint --xpath '//grammar-form[not(@normal-form)]' input.xml 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "There are missing normal forms."
else
    echo "There are no missing normal forms."
fi
```

In xpath mode, `xmllint` will print the matching paths, or if nothing matches, exit with a error code of 10 and print a message to that effect to standard error (the `--noout` option mentioned in the manpage to suppress output doesn't do anything in the version I'm testing with, unfortunately), hence the redirections.